# libGDX: Changing visibility of a 3d model

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx

Imagine I have a model of a human with some accessory like sunglasses, a hat, a chain and so on. Is there any way to switch the visibility of those items inside my libGDX application, by writing something like:

```
 modelInstance.getNode("sunglasses").setVisible(false)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a blending attibute to its material:

```
blendingAttribute = new BlendingAttribute(GL10.GL_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
material = modelinstance.materials.get(0);
material.set(blendingAttribute);
```

Then you can set its opacity like this:

```
blendingAttribute.opacity = 0.5F; //0-1
```

Comment: You are a life saver brother. :)

Comment: but this will not hide properly, still vertex count and drawcalls same